# Unauthorize Error to Azure App Configuration with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I'm using App Configuration and Key Vault for store my config. Firstly, I used access key where was Endpoint, Id and Secret. That is working fine, but it isn't secure, because Id and Secret are sensitive data.

I tried to use value after 'Endpoint=' and in Startup.cs set DefaultAzureCredential(), but always when I launch my Azure Function, I get 401 (Unauthorize error). Why do I get this and how could I fix that?

**ConfigureAppConfiguration in Startup**

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder);

            var configurationBuilder = builder.UseAppSettings().ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

            var connectionString = configurationBuilder["appConfiguration"];
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                options.Connect(new Uri(connectionString), credentials)
                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, builder.GetContext().EnvironmentName)
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    });
            });
        }
```

**appConfiguration from appsettings**

```
"appConfiguration": "https://rta-dev-edu-app-config.azconfig.io"
```

**Error**

> A host error has occurred during startup operation '9467e813-9979-44b9-8ecf-3d956fbaf72e'.
> Azure.Data.AppConfiguration: Service request failed.
> Status: 401 (Unauthorized)
> WWW-Authenticate: HMAC-SHA256,Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is from the wrong issuer. It must match the AD tenant associated with the subscription, to which the configuration store belongs. If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later.

P.S. I already added my account to IAM for my App Configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The access token is from the wrong issuer. It must match the AD tenant associated with the subscription, to which the configuration store belongs. If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later.

As Mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x#grant-your-app-access-to-key-vault) of Accessing the Key Vault from the Dot Net Core Application,

- you have to check that your account should have the multiple tenants access and then Set the Credential types such as `SharedTokenCacheTenantId`, `VisualStudioTenantId` to the `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions`while using the `DefaultAzureCrendential` in the required tenant.
- Your Azure Account should be logged in the Same tenant level as you're trying to access the app configuration resource from the same tenant.

Refer to the GitHub Issue #[14867](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/14867).